# Delete throwing destructor called from destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I understand that the current rules in C++ say that:

> if a destructor throws while already stack unwinding because of a exception then `std::terminate` is called.

While exploring why the rules are as they are, I came across the situation described in the code below.

1. The destructor of `X` throws.
2. `Y` deletes an `X` in its own destructor.
3. Therefore the destructor of `Y` throws.

It's not clear to me if the fact that `Y` throws (3.) should trigger `std::terminate` by the standard rules. I hope it should not, and testing against `gcc` runs as I hoped.

Can someone familiar with the standard legalese clarify this? Should (3.) trigger `std::terminate` or not?

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
  ~X() noexcept(false) {
    std::cout << "Destroying X\n";
    throw std::runtime_error("Exception");
  }
};

struct Y {
   X * x_;

  explicit Y(X * x) : x_{x} { }

  ~Y() noexcept(false) {
    std::cout << "Destroying Y\n";
    delete x_;
  }
};

int main() {
  try {
    Y y(new X());
    std::cout << "Living\n";
  }
  catch (const std::exception & e) {
    std::cout << "Caught " << e.what() << '\n';
  }
}
```

With g++ version 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9 with `--std=c++17` I get:

```
Living
Destroying Y
Destroying X
Caught Exception
```

Comment: Y isn't throwing an exception. The exception from X is not Y's exception.

Comment: @GreatBigBore So you're saying that in the following, `bar` isn't throwing an exception? `void foo() { throw 1; } void bar() { foo(); }` Where does the exception go?

Comment: The exception goes up to the first exception handler it can find. In your case, the handler in `main`, as your output shows.

Comment: Change your `X *` to a `shared_ptr`, don't delete `x_` manually, throw an exception in both destructors, and you'll see the termination. Look [**here**](https://pastebin.com/cSC0DzK6). In that example, Y is throwing an exception in its destructor--**now** you're in stack unwinding, and the exception from `~X()` is a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard says in [[except.terminate]p1.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.terminate#1.4):

> - when the destruction of an object during stack unwinding terminates by throwing an exception, or

2) happens because `y` goes out of scope. 1) throws an exception, which starts stack unwinding. During stack unwinding, more specifically while destroying `Y` - which is 2). It throws an exception, and so the point is satisfied and `std::terminate` is called.

Which is exactly what you're code is doing, except for an important point: **during stack unwinding**. Stack unwinding doesn't happen when a scope ends, it only happens when an exception is thrown and goes out of the current scope it was thrown.

`Y` isn't destroyed because of an exception. Add a `throw 1;` to see a call to `std::terminate` in action.

Thus, that clause doesn't apply and your code is indeed valid.